# What does an asterisk (*) mean when shown beside a field name in the attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, esri-geodatabase, attribute-table

What does an asterisk (*) mean when shown beside a field name in the attribute table?
I would think those are reserved field names but they are not.

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It means that the field is indexed. You can change the character used to indicate whether a field is indexed under the Table Options > Appearance menu:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! SO i guess those get generated automatically. Because I did not create any indexes.

Comment: I stand corrected. We did index those fields. THanks

Answer (score 10):

The asterisk means that the field has an index. A Shapefile does not have any indexed fields by default, you need to add them. A GeoDatabase Featureclass always has a spatial index on the Shape field and attribute index on the ObjectID.